# SSRS table not showing records

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I built my code in SSMS.  It returns 900 rows.  I ported the same code over to SSRS, ran it through Query Builder, it returns a lot of records.  Great!

For simplicity sake I just pull a table over to the report, point it to my newly created dataset that's showing rows upon rows of data returned (in the Query Builder).  I drag 1 column over (OrderID) to just make sure it's working.  I preview the report.

Nothing shows up in my table.

For troubleshooting purposes I write a simple sql statement to pull the top 100 rows from just one table, change the dataset to my new, test dataset & run it.  Runs fine.  I get a lot of pages of 1 column.  Table, dataset & datasource are connected and running fine.

Why does my statement, which works in SSMS and the query builder within SSRS, not return any data in SSRS table?

No, I haven't changed any properties or anything of the sort.

Exact same datasource in SSRS that I'm testing against in SSMS.

Here's a screenshot of my table as requested:
[image: My simplistic table]

Comment: Is the datasource used by the report in SSRS the same server that you're running the query on?  Can you post a screenshot of your table?

Comment: What do you mean by "I run the report"? The Preview tab in BIDS/Visual Studio?  Deploy and run on Report Manager? SharePoint?

Comment: I previewed it. (Clicked on the "Preview" tab). I apologize if I confused anyone by saying I ran the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this comes up again, it could very well be a corrupt datasource be it embedded or shared.

In my case it was shared.  I deleted it all together, recreated it, tested it and when I previewed the report, all my data was there.

Have a nice day.